# Mocking a method with possible null values in powermock

Tags: java, junit, tdd, mockito, powermock

I have a method which does the following as a part of the operation:

```
URL resourceUrl = new File(sampleString1.concat("/")
                .concat(sampleString2)).toURI().toURL();
```

SampleString1 and SampleString2 are populated by the constructor of the class and the class is an abstract class. I used the below line to test this class:

```
servlet = PowerMockito.mock(MyServlet.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

Through this i'm unable to set values of attributes sampleString1 and sampleString2 as i'm not passing them to constructor. Now, when i call my test method in servlet, i get NullPointerExceptions at the above mentioned line because of null values at sampleString1 and sampleString2. I tried to simulate that part by the following:

```
 PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).
                     withArguments(Matchers.anyString()).thenReturn(sampleFile);
```

but still it goes through the string concatanations when new file call is done and throws exception. How can i test this method? I just want to return a sample value for resourceUrl when new file operation is called and proceed with the logic in the method and test the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Whitebox API documented at the following locations:

- http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation
- http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.12/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html

It uses reflection to set the values on an object like so:

```
MyServlet servlet = PowerMockito.mock(MyServlet.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
Whitebox.setInternalState(servlet, "sampleString1", "foo");
Whitebox.setInternalState(servlet, "sampleString2", "bar");
//Test code...
```

Comment: I edited your answer with my code Matt but the solution is the same.. thanks.

Comment: Not sure why, but my edit has not appeared yet even though i added it 2 times.... anyway, the solution is the same, so no need to worry about it... thanks.

Comment: It was apparently rejected because it looked like a comment. I saw the edit though and updated accordingly.